# What is the meaning of this command

Tags: matlab

```
capi = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(b) sum(resulti == b,1),nonzeros(unique(resulti)), 'UniformOutput', false))
```

why when I used that code, my code cannot run and there was command like the following command?

```
??? Array dimensions must match for binary array op.
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html

Comment: if `resulti` is a row vector, it does the same as `bsxfun(@eq,resulti,nonzeros(unique(resulti)))` so check the size of `resulti` and compare with what you suppose it to be (with reference to that piece of code)

Answer (score 1):

All this can be found via Matlab's documentation, which should always be your first step!

Having said that, here's a breakdown of your command:

`cell2mat`: convert a cell array to a matrix according to some format you define

`arrayfun`: evaluate some function for all elements in an array. The function may be an anonymous function (e.g., `@(b) sum(resulti == b,1)`)

`sum`: sum all the elements of a matrix in a particular direction. Direction 1: down the rows, direction 2: along the columns, etc.

`nonzeros`: form new array by removing all zeros from the input array. This will output a column vector, irrespective of the input's shape.

`unique`: return the input array with all duplicates of all values removed. The output will also be sorted.

Type `help [command]` or `doc [command]` for more information on all these commands (which I recommend you do!)

Now, combining these into your command:

```
A = nonzeros(unique(resulti))
```

will return all unique entries in a column vector, with any zero removed.

```
B = arrayfun(@(b)sum(resulti==b), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

will run the function `@(b) sum(resulti == b,1)` on all entries of the newly created column vector `A`, and collect them in a cell-array `B` (cell, because `'UniformOutput'` is set to `false`). This function will simply compare each element of `resulti` against the running index `b`, and find the total count along the rows. Then, finally,

```
capi = cell2mat(B)
```

will convert the cell-array `B` back to a normal Matlab array.

The objective of this command seems to be to count the number of non-unique occurrences on each of the colums of `resulti`. As hinted at by @GuntherStruyf, this whole command seems a hacked-together, forced one-liner, rather than well-manageable, readable code. I would personally opt to break it over several lines, avoid `arrayfun` (slow) and instead use `bsxfun` or a `for`-loop (faster (yes, also the `for`-loop), better readable).

But that's a matter of opinion (which goes against popular opinion :)